# How to avoid having to skip fatal task errors with ansible?

Tags: ansible

When running ansible playbooks you do often encounter use-cases where a task (usually shell or command) is expected to return error codes.

So far the solution was to register the result and to add `ignore_errors: true` and to decide later if it was a real error or not.

Now, there is one issue with this: it will mess the logging as you will see red error like

```
fatal: ...
...ignoring
```

Is there a way to avoid these so we would not have fake errors in the logs?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983636/how-to-always-run-some-ansible-roles-after-previous-failures

Answer (score 13):

`failed_when` and `changed_when` is to help you:

```
- shell: echo good | grep bad
  register: res
  failed_when: false
  changed_when: false
```

This will always be good and green despite failed shell command.
You can also define a complex `failed_when` statement based on registered variable.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430875/1849837 (use `changed_when` and `failed_when`). Note that it works from Ansible since 1.4.

For older Ansible version the only way I see (and use) is do not run potentially failing task at all. You may use conditions (`when`) for that.

First you need to check the condition and assign the result of check to the variable

```
- name: "check if condition is met"
  command: some condition that populates result
  register: result

- name: "some operation"
   command: operation that runs only if result is not failed.
  when: result|failed
```

This includes some boilerplate code (you need artificial step to test the condition) but I see no better alternatives. I believe that this is better than polluting the logs with `fatal: ... ...ignoring`.

Comment: That a horrible hack, look at @Konstantin Suvorov answer.

Comment: I agree that your answer is better. But failed_when is available since ansible 1.4. I edited my and your answer to specify that.