# How to always run some ansible roles after previous failures?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have a set of playbooks that do look like

```
- name: Run test
  hosts: tester
  roles:
    - { role: setup_repos }
    - { role: setup_environment }
    - { role: install_packages }
    - { role: run_tests }
    - { role: collect_logs }
```

The current problem is that all over the first 4 roles we have `ignore_errors: true` which is not a good practice as it makes very hard to read the output and to debug.

The only reason why `ignore_errors` was abused was because we wanted to be able to perform the collect_logs at the end, regardless the outcome.

How can we refactor this in order to remove the ignore_errors and have a more of a fail-fast strategy.

Please note that we have lots of playbooks calling collect_logs role, so "moving code inside playbook" is not really a way to reuse it.

Comment: How about creating a playbook that runs the `collect_logs` role only and run it after the first completes?

Comment: This would be against a clean and simple user interface. It adds complexity to the user which is worst.

Comment: Drive your testing with a shell script that calls a standalone `collect_logs` playbook after everything else has completed, regardless of the exit status of previous ansible runs.  This way you can drop your `ignore_errors` and correctly report failures while still collecting logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ansible 2.4 or newer one should replace `role:` block with tasks like `role_include` or `role_import`, which gives you the ability to use normal logic used by tasks. You could use handlers, ignore_errors, and so on.

Comment: How do you use a handler with `include_role`?

Comment: @techraf no difference on handlers. If you want to force their execution after role, you meta to flush them.

Comment: So why do you mention handlers alongside ignore errors, if they do not behave the same?

Answer (score 0):

I belive handlers and notify would help you achive what you want.
You wont need to change your roles behavior (although it might be a good idea).

You should notify at the end of each of your roles, the handler would only run once.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change

Also if you choose to start handleing errors you could use the `--force-handlers` to force handler execution even when the playbook failed.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_error_handling.html#handlers-and-failure